# What's wrong with this jQuery $.getJSON YQL request?

Tags: jquery, json, yql

I would like to request JSON data via YQL..

This url represents the json object i would like to display:

```
http://localhost:8387/nscalemc/rest/mon/resourcestatus.json
```

So i changed the url to:

```
var yqlUrl = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8387%2Fnscalemc%2Frest%2Fmon%2Fresourcestatus.json%27%0A&format=json&callback=?"
```

And finally the getJSON() call:

```
$.getJSON(yqlUrl, function(data) {alert("data");});
```

The request returns null...

[image]

Any solution to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web cannot access *your* `localhost`. Think about it: `localhost` points to 127.0.0.1, which is the address of the machine the program is running on. In the case of your browser, this is your machine; in the case of the Yahoo API servers, it's *their* machine. So it can't work.

Comment: seems logic, how embarrassing :O

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your YQL query returns 0 results, so nothing is actually wrong.